# How to avoid redundant database queries while using serailizer validation and APIViews

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

There is situation where, in Django serializer, validation of a field needs to query the database for getting an object or a queryset. After successful validation, the APIView again requires to access the same object or query set. In such case how can we avoid duplicate queries?

Should we just avoid the validation in the serializer and instead do it in the APIView?
Or can we pass the fetched object or queryset to the validated_data attribute of the serializer, so that we can get it in the APIView?
Or else, is there a better way?

Comment: You can prefetch all the info you need in your qs using `prefetch_related` and `select_related`. Just prefetch it in your viewset queryset.

Comment: That's a different case. That is used when we want to prefetch data from the foreign key table. I am asking how to avoid duplicate queries from the same table.

Comment: I can't help you without an example as I don't understand this case.

Comment: Can you show your implementation and point out where you think the redundant queries are happening